# The serializable class NodeListImpl does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

Tags: java, generics

I'm pretty new to generics stuff. I'm experiencing "NodeListImpl is a raw type. References to generic type NodeListImpl should be parameterized" and have some question's about it, since i don't get all of it yet.

Code:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private String name;
    private T value;
    private NodeListImpl<Node<T>> nodes = new NodeListImpl<Node<T>>();

    public void addChild (Node<T> child) {
        this.nodes.add(child);
    }
}

public interface List<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    public abstract boolean contains(Object e);
    public abstract boolean add(T e);
    public abstract void addFirst(T e);
    public abstract T peekFirst();
    public abstract boolean isEmpty();
    public abstract T pollFirst();
    public abstract void clear();
}

public class ListImpl<T> extends LinkedList<T> implements List<T> {
}

public interface NodeList<Node> extends Iterable<Node> {
    public abstract boolean contains(Node e);
    public abstract boolean add(Node e);
    public abstract void addFirst(Node e);
    public abstract Node peekFirst();
    public abstract boolean isEmpty();
    public abstract Node pollFirst();
    public abstract void clear();
}

public class NodeListImpl<Node> extends LinkedList<Node> implements NodeList<Node> {

}
```

Task is:

1. Write a List, that can handle to store and operatore with all types of data. Example: A list of integers, a list of class B, etc.
2. Write a specialized version of that list, that can do the same, but only with Nodes.

Problems / Questions:

1. Since our List needs to be able to work with ALL types of data, i thought we would make it List. Is that correct?
2. Our NodeList only should be able to work with Nodes, so i made it NodeList. Is that correct?
3. As told before, i am getting "NodeListImpl is a raw type. References to generic type NodeListImpl should be parameterized". I do understand that, Node itself has a generic Type since it needs to store a variable type of value. And when i say NodeListImpl it somehow blocks the view of Node. So i tried something like NodeListImpl> which doesn't work. What do i do wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where do you get the warning from 3. Please state the line of that warning.

Comment: @ gexicide: i get that warning in "public interface NodeList<Node> extends Iterable<Node>".

Answer (score 0):

Considering 1:

`List<T>` is fine.

Considering 2:
Your `NodeList` class is wrong. `class NodeList<Node>...` declares a class `NodeList` with a *type parameter* named `Node` which will shadow your class `Node`. What you should write:

```
class NodeList<T extends Node>
```

then you have a class with a type parameter `T`, but `T` must be a subclass of `Node`.

Considering 3:
Your node class is also a template class, so it also needs a parameter `T`, e.g. `NodeList<T extends Node<T>>`. But why is `Node` generic?

Comment: Node is generic, because Node needs to be able to save different kinds of values. String, Int, Class B etc. So i made it generic. Am i wrong here?

Comment: Btw: I don't want T to be a subclass of Node. What i want is that NodeList can only be a list of Nodes and Node itself can store all types of values in itself. Thats all...